# What is the meaning of "v5.15/standard/base" v/s "v5.15/base"in yocto kernel bb files

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I see a lot of files having strings in yocto bsp layer that lack explanation as to what those branches are about. I often see these kind of lines:

`KBRANCH:<machine> ?= "v5.15/standard/base"`

`KBRANCH:<machine> ?= "v5.15/base"`

While understand that the string refers to a specific branch of yocto kernel git repo, it doesn't explain the branching model clearly. What is `standard/base` v/s `base` ?
How do i pick a stable branch ?